# Can you explain about the lyrics put off here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, lyrics

Questions about grammatical constructions in the song "If we were a movie" ([Lyrics](http://www.metrolyrics.com/if-we-were-a-movie-lyrics-hannah-montana.html))

> Watching the sunset fade to black, show the names, play the happy song, yeah

Whom or about what she said when she said 'show the names, play the song'?Is it to the sun?

> And I'd be the best friend that you fall in love with.

Here, *with whom* could also be used in place of *that*?*That* seems a bit weird when it is used for a person, instead of *whom*.

> Wish I could tell you there's a kiss like something more than in my mind.

It means something more than kiss like in my mind.Doesn't the awkward position of words seems like 'more than in my mind,' maybe in heart?

Comment: "fade to black, show the names, play the happy song" is a way to describe when the [end credits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closing_credits) roll. This is only one small part of your question, though, as your question has several questions.

Comment: In everyday speech (or songs that use everyday speech–which are probably most songs), *that* is often used to refer to a person. See [this grammar blog](http://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2006/11/that-who.html) and the song title "You're the one that I want." Also it would not be *with whom you fall in love with*; you would need to delete one of those *withs*.

Comment: updated link of source

Comment: Okay, but I've edited your link to give the song's name in the question, as just the name of the song can provide context, especially if it is a popular song. Plus you should always name the source of anything you quote.